# extract content from many files based on constant file

Tags: bash, awk

I have a constant file (File1) and more than 50 files. I want to match Chr from File1 with all other files and if its true then I want give condition Start >= Pos && End < Pos to extract content of all files using awk or any other language in bash script.

Here is an example.(For the simplicity I have used only two files here)

File1 (constant file)

> Chr    Satrt    End
>
> > 1    86    99
> >
> > 5    1223    23455
> >
> > 6    56    100

File2

> Chr    Pos    depth
>
> > 1    87    0
> >
> > 1    88    1
> >
> > 1    89    1
> >
> > 1    90    1
> >
> > 1    92    2
> >
> > 1    93    3
> >
> > 2    23    1
> >
> > 2    24    1

output

> Chr    Pos     depth
>
> > 1    87    0
> >
> > 1   88   1
> >
> > 1   89   1
> >
> > 1   90   1
> >
> > 1   92   2
> >
> > 1   93   3

Please advice me how can I this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{s[$1]=$2;e[$1]=$3;next}$1 in s && $2 >s[$1] && $2 <e[$1]' file1 file2
```

this one-liner works for your example (the header line was skipped, you can add `NR(orFNR)>1`). you can at least get the idea

it outputs:

```
kent$  awk 'NR==FNR{s[$1]=$2;e[$1]=$3;next}$1 in s && $2 >s[$1] && $2 <e[$1]' f f2 
1 87 0
1 88 1
1 89 1
1 90 1
1 92 2
1 93 3
```

explanation:

```
Assume the columns were separated by whitespace.

NR==FNR{s[$1]=$2;e[$1]=$3;next}

here for the first file (your file1), save two arrays, s[] (start) and e[] (end). the index is first column value.



$1 in s && $2 >s[$1] && $2 <e[$1]

for the 2nd file (your file2), each row, we print it out if 3 conditions were satisfied:

1) $1 should be an index in s[] (or e[] same here)
2) $2 > s[$1]
3) $2 < e[$1]
```

Comment: Thanks @Kent. Can you please explain me the code? I tried it and there might be some bug. It starts perfectly with $2 >s[$1] but doesn't ends on this $3 <e[$1] condition. It gives all the Pos after $2 >s[$1]

Comment: try `$3 < 1*e[$1]` got better result?

Comment: its not working @Kent. can you please explain the code?

Comment: @user3378320 brief explanation added.

Comment: Thank you Kent I changed it to $2 >s[$1] && $2 <=e[$1]'. Now it worked.

Comment: @user3378320 oh, that was a stupid bug... sorry, I fix the answer immediately